# Как добавить автообновление страницы на сайт

Tags: php, html

Как добавить автообновление страницы на сайт и возврат на страницу с которой были отправленные данные с помощью post

Answer (score 1):

все разобрался

```
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: Ответ не полон! Вы забыли вторую строку `exit;`.

Answer (score 0):

Автообновление и переход по URL:
header("Refresh:10; url=http://site.ru");
1) 10 - через 10 секунд обновит и перейдет по url;
2) url - указывается полный с http://.